# Why is this call to a dynamic library function so slow?

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am writing a shared library for python to call. Since this is my first time using python's `ctypes` module, and nearly my first time writing a shared library, I have been writing both C and python code to call the library's functions.

For the heck of it I put some timing code in and found that, while most calls of the C program to the library are very fast, the first is slow, considerably slower than its python counterpart in fact. This goes against everything I expected and was hoping that someone could tell me why.

Here is a stripped down version of the header file from my C library.

```
typedef struct MdaDataStruct
{
    int numPts;
    int numDists;
    float* data;
    float* dists;
} MdaData;

//allocate the structure
void* makeMdaStruct(int numPts, int numDist);

//deallocate the structure
void freeMdaStruct(void* strPtr);

//assign the data array
void setData(void* strPtr, float* divData);
```

Here is the C program that calls the functions:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    clock_t t1, t2;
    t1=clock();
    long long int diff;
    //test the allocate function
    t1 = clock();
    MdaData* dataPtr = makeMdaStruct(10, 3);
    t2 = clock();
    diff = (((t2-t1)*1000000)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("make struct, took: %d microseconds\n", diff);

    //make some data
    float testArr[10] = {0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9};

    //test the set data function
    t1 = clock();
    setData(dataPtr, testArr);
    t2 = clock();
    diff = (((t2-t1)*1000000)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("set data, took: %d microseconds\n", diff);

    //test the deallocate function
    t1 = clock();
    freeMdaStruct(dataPtr);
    t2 = clock();
    diff = (((t2-t1)*1000000)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("free struct, took: %d microseconds\n", diff);

    //exit
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the python script that calls the functions:

```
# load the library
t1 = time.time()
cs_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libChiSq.so")
t2 = time.time()
print "load library, took", int((t2-t1)*1000000), "microseconds"
# tell python the function will return a void pointer
cs_lib.makeMdaStruct.restype = c_void_p
# make the strcuture to hold the MdaData with 50 data points and 8 L dists
t1 = time.time()
mdaData = cs_lib.makeMdaStruct(10,3)
t2 = time.time()
print "make struct, took", int((t2-t1)*1000000), "microseconds"
# make an array with the test data
divDat = np.array([0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9], np.float32)
#run the function to load the array into the struct
t1 = time.time()
cs_lib.setData(mdaData, divDat.ctypes.data)
t2 = time.time()
print "set data, took", int((t2-t1)*1000000), "microseconds"
#free the structure
t1 = time.time()
cs_lib.freeMdaStruct(mdaData)
t2 = time.time()
print "free struct, took", int((t2-t1)*1000000), "microseconds"
```

and finally, here is the output of running the two consecutively:

```
[]$ ./tester
make struct, took: 60 microseconds
set data, took: 2 microseconds
free struct, took: 2 microseconds
[]$ python so_py_tester.py 
load library, took 77 microseconds
make struct, took 3 microseconds
set data, took 23 microseconds
free struct, took 10 microseconds
```

As you can see, the C call to makeMdaStruct takes 60us and the python call to makeMdaStruct takes 3us, which is highly confusing.

My best guess was that somehow the C code pays the cost of loading the library at the first call? Which confuses me because I thought that the library was loaded when the program was loaded into memory.

**Edit:** I think there might be a kernel of truth to the guess because I put an extra untimed call to makeMdaStruct and freeMdaStruct before the timed call to makeMdaStruct and got the following output in testing:

```
[]$ ./tester
make struct, took: 1 microseconds
set data, took: 1 microseconds
free struct, took: 0 microseconds
[]$ python so_py_tester.py 
load library, took 70 microseconds
make struct, took 4 microseconds
set data, took 23 microseconds
free struct, took 12 microseconds
```

Comment: You may be seeing the time it takes to initialize `malloc`. Add the following before the initial test: `malloc_stats(); malloc(0); malloc_stats();`. The `malloc(0)` call works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My best guess was that somehow the C code pays the cost of loading the library at the first call? Which confuses me because I thought that the library was loaded when the program was loaded into memory.

You are correct in both cases. The library is *loaded* when the program is loaded. However, the dynamic loader/linker defers *symbol resolution* until function invocation time.

Calls to shared libraries are done so indirectly, via an entry in the *procedure linkage table* (PLT). Initially, all of the entries in the PLT point to `ld.so`. Upon the first call to a function, `ld.so` looks up the actual address of the symbol, updates the entry in the PLT, and jumps to the function. This is "lazy" symbol resolution.

You can set the`LD_BIND_NOW` environment variable to change this behavior.  From [`ld.so(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

> `LD_BIND_NOW`
>                 (libc5; glibc since 2.1.1) If set to a nonempty string, causes the dynamic linker to resolve all symbols at program startup instead of deferring function call
>                 resolution to the point when they are first referenced.  This is useful when using a debugger.

This behavior can also be changed at link time. From [`ld(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html):

> ```
>   -z keyword
>       The recognized keywords are:
>       ...
>       lazy
>            When generating an executable or shared library, mark it to
>            tell the dynamic linker to defer function call resolution to
>            the point when the function is called (lazy binding), rather
>            than at load time.  Lazy binding is the default.
> ```

Further reading:

- http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/01/sorry-state-of-dynamic-libraries-on-linux/

Comment: Ah, this explains a great deal. Thank you very much. I would accept your answer now, but SO wants me to wait 7 more minutes.

Comment: Did you test this for the OP's setup? I tried permutations of exporting `LD_BIND_NOW` and building the test program and shared library with `-z now`. I only managed to eliminate the initial delay on the first `makeMdaStruct` call by preceding it with `malloc(0)`. Surely the allocator has internal data structures and locks that need to be set up, and maybe it's also lazy.